# How to make Transparent letters with shadow?

Tags: html, css

I have transparent letters with a **text-shadow** on my design, but if we are making letters transparent and add **text-shadow** it fill letters with a color.
I need smth like on img below.

I added `-webkit-text-stroke-`

[image: img]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It makes sense that with transparent text the color would show through from the shadow because the shadow has color.

Comment: Howdy! Welcome to SO! Generally this isn't a site where you just provide requirements and have folks do your work. You'll get more productive responses if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you tried and what didn't work first.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. But you need to change your font style.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 2">
  <text x="5" y="1" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1" fill="none" stroke-width=".015" stroke="#fff" font-family="sans-serif">SPORT</text>
</svg>
```

If you want to use `-webkit-text-stroke-`

```css
body { background:black; 
        }
span {
        color: transparent;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
       -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<span>SPORT</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) :

> The `mix-blend-mode` CSS property sets how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's parent and the element's background.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/120/abstract/2), linear-gradient(45deg,yellow,blue,gray,tomato,lime,purple);/* gradient if img do not load */
  font-size: 3em;
}

h1 {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;/* black will totally blend with what's underneath */
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 3px white
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>SPORT</h1>
</header>
```